# If $T_1, \dots, T_r$ are commutative, dim($V$) = $n,$ and nullity($T_i$) = $n_i,$ then rank($T_1 \cdots T_r$) $\geq n - \sum_{i = 1}^{r} n_i.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_r$ be commutative operators on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V.$ For each $i = 1, 2, \dots, r,$ let $n_i$ = nullity($T_i$). Prove that rank($T_1 T_2 \cdots T_r$) $\geq n - \sum_{i = 1}^{r} n_i.$

$Proof.$ We proceed by induction on $r.$ Clearly, when $r = 1,$ the result holds by the rank-nullity theorem. We suppose that the inequality holds for some integer $k \geq 2.$ We claim that the result holds for $k + 1.$ We define the restriction of $T_{k+1}$ to the range of $T_k \cdots T_1$ to be the map $$ \overline{T}_{k+1} = T\, \big|\,_{R_{T_k \cdots T_1}}:\, {R_{T_k \cdots T_1}} \to {R_{T_{k+1} \cdots T_1}}.$$ Observe that by our inductive hypothesis, we have

\begin{align*}
\mbox{rank}(T_1 \cdots T_{k+1}) &= \mbox{rank}(T_1 \cdots T_k) - \mbox{nullity}(T_{k+1}) \\ \\
&\geq n - \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i - n_{k+1} = n - \sum_{i = 1}^{k+1} n_i, \\
\end{align*}

as desired. By the Principle of Mathematical Induction, therefore, the inequality holds. $\quad \square$

I am curious as to whether this argument holds. It seems a bit convenient. I happen to know, furthermore, that nullity($T_1 \cdots T_r$) $\leq n_1 + \dots + n_r.$ But why does this latter inequality hold? If anyone could shed some light or intuition on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! This is a nice quertion. Your proof looks OK. It would be good to mention where you are using that the $T_i$ are commuting (this is needed to show that $T_{k+1}$ maps the range of $T_1 \dots T_k$ to itself).

Comment: You can prove that $\operatorname{nullity} \left(T_1 T_2 \cdots T_r\right) \leq n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_r$ by induction over $r$ (using the fact that $\operatorname{nullity} \left(AB\right) \leq \operatorname{nullity} A + \operatorname{nullity} B$ for any two composable linear maps $A$ and $B$). The commutativity of $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_r$ is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty good modulo some small errors.

Rank-Nullity says that $$\text{rank}(\overline{T}_{k+1}) = \text{rank}(T_k\dots T_1) - \text{nullity}(\overline{T}_{k+1})$$

Next we note that $$\text{nullity}(\overline{T}_{k+1}) \leq \text{nullity}(T_{k+1})$$

and

$$\text{rank}(T_{k+1} T_k \dots T_1) = \text{rank}(\overline{T}_{k+1}).$$

Combining these together then allows you to apply the hypothesis of induction to get the desired result.

I rescind my statement that the commuting of the operators is important. Truth be told, it doesn't matter that the codomain you chose for the restriction is too large. There was another fact I was worried about, but I can't see any flaws with the argument here, and it doesn't refer to the commuting. Therefore unless someone else can spot a flaw here, I must believe that the commuting is extraneous.